# Save a copy of the current attachment before sending

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

How do I save a copy of attachment I just attached before I send as a backup.

Any help would be great! Thank you.

```
    Dim outlookOBJ As Object
    Dim MItem As Object

   Set outlookOBJ = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set MItem = outlookOBJ.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   With MItem
   .To = "email1@gmail.com"
  '.cc = "email2@gmail.com"
   .Subject = " Test Subject"
   .body = " test text in body of email" & Me.EvalID_T1.Value
   .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BrowseFile").Cells(4,3).Value)
   'want to add some kind of save current attachment feature here right before I send

    .send
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thank you Tim!  I was looking at the wrong method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Simply use `For Each … In … Next Loop` to save current [MItem.Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachments-object-outlook)*

```
With MItem
    .To = "email1@gmail.com"
    '.cc = "email2@gmail.com"
    .Subject = " Test Subject"
    .Body = " test text in body of email" & Me.EvalID_T1.value
    .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BrowseFile").Cells(4, 3).value)

     Dim Atmt As Object
     For Each Atmt In MItem.Attachments
         Debug.Print Atmt.DisplayName
         Atmt.SaveAsFile "C:\Temp\" & Atmt.DisplayName
     Next

    .Display
End With
```